# notifyItemChanged not refreshing view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

First of all, I worked on this all day but could not get anything done. I have a `RecyclerView` with an adapter that uses `RecyclerView`'s  `SortedList`. I tried implementing `TouchHelper` with the callback class:

```
public class TimerListTouchHelperCallback extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {

    private OnItemChangeListener onItemChangeListener;

    public TimerListTouchHelperCallback(OnItemChangeListener listener, int dragDirs, int swipeDirs) {
        super(dragDirs, swipeDirs);

        this.onItemChangeListener = listener;

    }

    @Override
    public int getSwipeDirs(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        TimerHolder holder = (TimerHolder) viewHolder;

        int holderState = holder.getState();

        if (holderState == TimerHolder.TIMER_PENDING_DELETE) return 0;
        else return super.getSwipeDirs(recyclerView, viewHolder);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return false;
    }




    @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {
        TimerHolder holder = (TimerHolder) viewHolder;

        int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
        // ViewHolder's state is changed that should handle the layout change.
        holder.setState(TimerHolder.TIMER_PENDING_DELETE); 

        if (onItemChangeListener != null) onItemChangeListener.onItemSwiped(position);
    }


    protected interface OnItemChangeListener{
        void onItemSwiped(int position);
    }
}
```

Here is the initialization of the TouchHelper

```
timerAdapter = new TimerAdapter(this, timerList);
    timerListView.setAdapter(timerAdapter);

TimerListTouchHelperCallback touchHelperCallback = new TimerListTouchHelperCallback(
        timerAdapter,
        ItemTouchHelper.LEFT,
        ItemTouchHelper.LEFT);

ItemTouchHelper swipeToDismissTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(touchHelperCallback);

swipeToDismissTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(timerListView);
```

My adapter implements the interface `OnItemChangeListener`

```
@Override
public void onItemSwiped(int position) {
    notifyItemChanged(position);
    removalPendingTimers.add(timerList.get(position));
}
```

My `ViewHolder` reads the state and when the state is `TimerHolder.TIMER_PENDING_DELETE` it hides the rest of the view and shows the interface with an undo button. But this is not happening until I scroll the view out and scroll it back again. Any suggestions what I am missing?

[image: Problem case]

Links

[Adapter class](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23067653/)
[ViewHolder class](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23067643/)

Comment: shouldn't you remove the item from your item list when it is swiped and then notify the adapter?

Comment: `OnItemSwiped` will call a handler to remove the item later, just like in gmail app.

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: if it calls a handler `later` then this is the problem, it notifies adapter before it makes the change. I guess @Dawid van Graan has given the answer or something close to it.

Comment: I do not want the items to be removed at that instant but rather give an option to Undo the deletion. The problem is the layout containing the Undo button is not shown even after calling notifyItemChanged.

Comment: which library are you using?

Comment: I am using support library 23.4.0
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0
com.android.support:design:23.4.0
com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0

Comment: let me create a project and check your code

Comment: please give full code of your adapter class and initialization for it so that I can debug it faster.

Comment: I have added the links to the classes.

Comment: thanks, I'll give it my best to help you

Comment: Okay and thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Finally got it running. Since `notifyItemChanged` was not cutting it (which it should have), I used `notifyItemRemoved` followed by `notifyItemInserted`.

Lags just a little bit but works.

Comment: I'm currently running into the same issue and using `notifyItemRemoved` followed by `notifyItemInserted` seems to work.  Oddly `notifyDataSetChanged` also works but not`notifyItemChanged`.  It's not an ideal fix but better then refreshing the entire list.

Comment: on my `dimissListener` i needed to add a `notifyItemChanged` to get work perfectly

Answer (score 3):

I've created a simple example Android App to better understand the question.

It makes use of **notifyItemChanged(position);** when the user swipes the item left or right to show the **undo** view. When the undo time expires it calls **notifyItemRemoved(position)** to remove it from the list. See the GIF for example, does not leave any empty rows.

https://github.com/DawidvanGraan/ExampleRecycleViewSwipeDismiss

Comment: I was looking at the code all night yesterday, and it seems there is something wrong with my implementation of recyclerview and adapter and not with the TouchHelperClass